# When does Google BigQuery's TOP function return approximate results?

Tags: sql, performance, google-bigquery

I have a table and I want to return the most frequent value of a certain column. Usually, one would do that using the classical `GROUP BY ... ORDER BY ... LIMIT`. I stumbled upon the BigQuery's `TOP` function and I got interested in it, since the documentation states that it is generally faster. However, the documentation also says that it *"may only return approximate results*". When does this happen and is the usage of `TOP` function generally worth it when one needs accurate results?

Full description from the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#top-function):

> TOP is a function that is an
>   alternative to the GROUP BY clause. It is used as simplified syntax
>   for `GROUP BY ... ORDER BY ... LIMIT ....` Generally, the TOP function
>   performs faster than the full `... GROUP BY ... ORDER BY ... LIMIT ...`
>   query, but may only return approximate results.

Comment: I am aware of the practices on SO, yet your answer doesn't directly address the questions I asked, thus I cannot accept it. I appreciate your time though, so it does indeed deserve an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

below might more fit for comment - but too lengthy, so I put it into answer

So far, from my experience it is just good as to have simplified alternative to GROUP BY - that is, btw, applicable only in simple scenarios: `A query that uses the TOP() function can return only two fields: the TOP field, and the COUNT(*) value.`

That said  - I don't see discrepancy in counts, while I do see it runs faster.
So, check below comparison that I run against table with 2.5B rows. As you can see - counts are exactly the same and run-time is 15% faster

[image]

[image]

At the same time if you will run similar queries and check `Query Plan Explanation` - you will see totally different execution pattern that might lead to different result but i was not able to catch such use case

Comment: With only 5 different elements, keeping a running count is easy: You only need 5 counters. With 1,000,000 different elements you need enough memory for a million different counters. TOP() is able to show you the top elements using way less memory, at the price of giving approximate results. That's why TOP is way faster, and why you are getting exact results here :).